# Yandex Navigator / Maps - Determining user location

Tags: gps, geolocation, yandex

I am an active user of Yandex.Navigator App (available for all kind of mobile platforms). Whenever I open the App, even though my GPS is turned off, it shows me my current location up to a great extent of precision on the map.

How they are obtaining my location without asking me to turn GPS on?

Are they using my mobile network connection, 3G internet connection, some new technology or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1479209 thread has your answer. Shortly, it uses the Mac address of the AP to determine approximately where you are.

Comment: Thanks Onur for this old query. I must say Yandex is smart enough.